# Ошибка установки Dart Pub в Linux

Tags: linux, angularjs, веб-программирование, npm, angular2

Здравствуйте. Ставлю Angular 2, один из шагов — установка Dart. В инструкции на оф. сайте написано, что Pub идет вместе с Dart сразу при установке, но его нет. Я попробовал установить его сам через npm и добавить путь к нему в path. При выполнении команды любой (в моем случае нужно было выполнить `pub get`) выдает ошибку: `[Error: No configuration directory found.]`. Ну, вот и вся проблема. Как починить? ОС: Debian 8.

Comment: так посмотрите, к каким файлам/каталогам программа пытается обратиться: `strace -e open pub get`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin
сделал, но все еще не понимаю, в чем дело.
https://jsfiddle.net/w5qutp1z/

Comment: каталог `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pub/node_modules/confdir/` у вас существует?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да. Все, что в выводе программы есть, все существует.

Comment: судя по всему, сообщение выдаёт вот этот файл: https://github.com/pvorb/node-confdir/blob/master/confdir.js // он присутствует среди тех, к которым происходит обращение. попробуйте разобраться с логикой функции и её параметрами.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в файлы я уже заглядывал, но где что эти скрипты ищут я понять не в состоянии. Там цепочка этих параметров идет из файлов выше. Вообще, на самом деле ни на одной машине с линуксом не ставится Pub.

Comment: 1. можете «зарепортить баг» разработчику. 2. можете сами разобраться (если вы программист). абсолютно стандартным при отладке написанного на скриптовых языках методом: записью значений интересующих параметров/переменных в какой-нибудь файл.